Match only exact string not partial
- name: Installed packages.
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: apt list --installed | cut -d'/' -f1 | uniq
  register: installed_packages

- name: Install packages.
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  when: 'item | string not in installed_packages.stdout'
  loop:
    - 7zip
    - acl

I have above task. Works great EXCEPT that 'string' matches partial package names. Meaning if I want to install the 'acl' package it gets skipped because 'libacl1' is installed. I need it to match the whole package name and ONLY the whole package name.
Is there any way to do this?

What's wrong with using the package_facts module?

And the check itself is basically useless. Just state what packages you want to have installed, Ansible will only install them if they aren't installed already.

package facts module did the trick.!

The check is still useless. You are just duplicating what the apt module already does. Now it's checked two times if the package is installed.

It is not useless when you ate trying to speed things up as much as you can if a role is run, and all the packages are already installed. Doing the check beforehand makes the role run in ~5 seconds instead of ~30.

Delete the separate check step. Package modules are desired state and do only what is necessary according to their input parameters.
Delete the loop. Most package modules can install a list in one transaction, which is faster. The list can either be static in the task, or a variable expression.
- name: Install packages.
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    name: 
    - 7zip
    - acl
    state: present


Doing this if the packages are already installed makes the role run in ~30 seconds. Doing the check beforehand runs in ~5 seconds.
